# ksdensity Matlab function in Python

Tags: python, matlab, kernel-density

I want to translate this function from Matlab to Python:

```
x = [randn(30,1); 5+randn(30,1)];
pi = linspace(.01,.99,99);
ksdensity(x,pi,'Function','icdf');
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(x)
kde.fit()
kde.icdf
```

How can I evaluate the icdf at pi?